# jQuery Dialog - Array defined in dialog is not removed on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm facing a typical problem with jQuery dialog.

I am basically doing some javascript operations after which I am updating a simple JS array in the dialog. A "process" button will pass the array values to the server. If I click "close" on dialog the dialog is simply removed.

However, upon re-creating the dialog, the array of the previous session remains i.e it still has some size. It is not removed along with the dialog.

I tried everything. For ex: in the parent page:

```
close: function() 
{
$("#dialog").remove();                      
array.length=0;
array=[];
}
```

Or within the dialog during script initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var array = new array();
array.length=0;
}
```

Or even trigger a call when I click the dialog close button:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function(){
*remove array*
});
```

Nothing. Zero. Zippo. The array remains. As you may have guessed, this is playing havoc with my server updates and I'm not sure what the problem may be.

If anyone of you has a solution, I'd be much obliged.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When I try it, it works.

here is my snippet:

```
  window.onload = function () {
     var array = ['foo', 'bar'];

     console.log(array);

     array = [];

     console.log(array);
  }
```

the first output contains the elements. the second output is empty.
maybe the problem is, that you have to say array = new Array() instead of "new array()".
but using the literals [] definitly works for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I figured out the problem. It had nothing to do with the actual dialog but the event delegation in my javascript contributed to the error. Basically, the array gets updated on the result of checking a checkbox. I binded the checkboxes using "live" handler. This created a duplicate event binding which also pointed to the previously created array. I removed "live" and it worked perfectly. I have to investigate how the array could be referenced even after removing the dialog. Once again a big thanks to you two!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it working for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = new Array();
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); },
                "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
            },
            close: function () { alert(array); array = new Array(); },
            open: function () { alert(array); }
        });

        $("#showDialog").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });

        $("#updateArray").click(function () {
            array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html:

```
<input type="button" id="showDialog" value="Show Dialog" />
<div id="dialog">
    Aliquam elementum ut? Tincidunt mattis in, ac ut, a cursus integer, habitasse? Elementum
    proin? Sit amet et elementum pulvinar integer, non, tortor dis in. Pulvinar dictumst!
    Turpis. Ultricies augue habitasse? Hac nunc integer risus enim ac? Ut nisi nisi
    magna velit elementum diam auctor purus et amet a!
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="updateArray" value="Update Array" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I checked your solution and it still doesn't work. Your method is spot on. I am now checking my javascript operations to see if they are affecting the issue.